# Rich Text Editor--Issue in creating and maintaining bullet list

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, richedit, ui-design

I have created a bullet list in my rich edit control, but I am facing below issue which I am trying to tell you in a sequence.

1. press a bullet button to generate a bullet.
2. Bullet list/paragraph will start like MS word.
3. save the document.
4. Reload the same doc --> Now it is behaving strangely. It adds protection around bullet due to which user cannot delete bullet, also paragraph will not be maintained, a user needs to click again on the bullet button to start bullet paragraph.

***see the code below:***

## code sample

```
   PARAFORMAT Pfm;
    richedit->GetParaFormat(Pfm);
Pfm.cbSize = sizeof(PARAFORMAT);
Pfm.dwMask = PFM_NUMBERING;


Pfm.wNumbering = PFN_BULLET;

richedit->SetParaFormat(Pfm);
richedit->SetFocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using Document View Arch, then try this code

   ```
   PARAFORMAT Pfm = this->GetParaFormatSelection();
   Pfm.cbSize = sizeof(PARAFORMAT);
   Pfm.dwMask = PFM_NUMBERING;


   Pfm.wNumbering = PFN_BULLET;

   this->SetParaFormat(Pfm);
   this->SetFocus();
   ```
2. If you are using Control, Save your document in RTF Format. This will persist your bullet structure as it is. Rich Text Box understands RTF format and can read and save a document as it is.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but now i am working on the maintaining indent . i tried also to put indent it worked, but it is not generating proper RTF file so while loading it again is loosing start indention and other formating like tabs/offset/space before/apace after.

So could any one help me.

thanks